# How do I programmatically extract a rake task's description?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I'm attempting to capture the equivalent of `rake -D` programmatically. I can load the Rakefile I'm targeting and see a list of tasks, but I can not figure out how to get the descriptions.

This will let me see the tasks that I am interested in:

```
  Dir.chdir @myTarget
  rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake.application = rake
  rake.init
  rake.load_rakefile
  tasks = Rake.application.tasks
  puts tasks.inspect
```

The above outputs something similar to:

```
  [<Rake::Task default => [test]>, <Rake::Task foodcritic => []>, <Rake::Task integration => [kitchen:all]>]
```

My question is how to access the desc comments that are visible if I run `rake -D`.  Here's what I'm after:

```
  rake foodcritic
      Run Foodcritic lint checks

  rake integration
      Alias for kitchen:all

  rake kitchen:all
      Run all test instances
```

Here's the final solution. The key was that I was missing metadata from the taskmanager:

```
  Dir.chdir @myTarget
  rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true
  Rake.application = rake
  rake.init
  rake.load_rakefile
  Rake.application.tasks.each do |t, n|
    puts t
    puts t.full_comment
    puts "\n"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the methods `comment` or `full_comment` for that. More docs on the [Rake::Task class here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html).

Comment: How do I access those? If I loop through the tasks being generated above I do not get output from task.full_comment or task.comment

Comment: I was missing Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true ... it's working now!